# Create L2TP/IPSec VPN Client in Android Programically

Tags: android, android-studio, vpn, android-vpn-service, l2tp

I am working on an Android app using Android Studio and what I am trying to do is building a simple VPN client that implements and L2TP protocols.

I have googled and searched here in Stack Overflow and I have looked at the Android SDK VPN sample called toyvpn and also looked at the official documentation for the VPN Service class.

How to implement L2TP with VpnService on the Android Platform? Are there any code samples, libraries, or even a starting point to such an implementation?

I have read about VpnService and VpnService.Builder but could not get any method to set VPN type to PPTP or L2TP, even I didn't get any method where I can set user/ password.

Comment: Did you eventually find a work around?

Comment: Nope bro, try an alternative way i.e openvpn